# OpenCart - not sending emails form default contact page

Tags: php, opencart

I have installed OC and it's working fine but i am not receiving any mail when my customers send us email by using contact us form

/index.php? ... information/contact

I have tried both options (mail and SMTP) but result are nothing, can any one tell me there is any specific setting which i need or any other reason which blocking mails please share so that i can resolved this issue.

Here is a screenshot of my mail settings:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to admin panel

```
System->setting
```

You will find you `store` in a list, click on the `edit` ,  give your email id there.

Now you can get you customer mail.

Comment: what is you smtp port ?

Comment: add your email in the addition email address option, and give a try.

Comment: check you sever mail port may be it has been shut down. For this also it can be happend

Comment: I have also try this option but still the issue. I have also not received any confirmatiom email on order create by customer.

Comment: Can you please let me know how i can enable sever mail port if this is problem.

Comment: http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/888/Checking+your+outgoing+mail+server+(Is+Port+25+blocked%3F)  check this i may be helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Change '-F' to lowercase '-f' in your mail parameters.  The format should be

```
-fjohndoe@example.com
```

Comment: I have tryed both '-F' and '-f' but still probilem

Comment: check you sever mail port may be it has been shut down. For this also it can be happend –

Comment: Don't try both, use only the correct version '-f'.  If you've got an email set, and nothing wrong with your mail parameters then chances are this is an issue with your server MTA.  Are you the server admin?  If not, you should consult with your hosting provider as there are such a wide array of possible causes here it would be too broad to address.

Comment: You can read more about additional paramters here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I have also used '-f' . I am not the server admin.

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was that regular mails did come over, but just the contact form did not work. This only happened because my server would not send emails with a "From:" header in which the domain differs from the current host (website / spam exploit protection).

The solution can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41576022/1493455).