# OpenCart 2.0.1.1 order notifications not working

Tags: php, opencart, sendmail

Hopefully someone can help. My contact form and adding order history and clicking "notify customer" are working perfectly. The only thing that isn't working is the automated emails to the customer when an order is placed, new account is made etc.

[image: OpenCart 2.0.1.1 Mail]

I'm 100% confident the email settings are correct. I have no errors in the log files and I've also tried various other things including port 587, changing "Mail" to "SMTP", I've tried changing the `-f` so that there is no space - but now I'm just completely stuck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using mail protocol without any parameters and it works fine for me.
Check your `catalog/model/checkout/order.php` to make sure that your code correct. Try to debug your `confirm` method.

Watch this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306766/opencart-not-sending-emails-notifications-or-contact-page?rq=1), may be it help you.